# Encoding PathBuf containing path with invalid utf-8 characters using serde in Rust

Tags: rust, encoding, utf-8, serde

I have a struct with pathbuf as one of its field,
struct A {
pub first: bool,
pub path: PathBuf,
}
Then path can have invalid utf-8 characters as linux allow to create files and folder with invalid utf-8 characters.
I am using rmp_serde::to_vec_named() to get vec from the struct object.
But, In case of path with invalid utf-8 characters, it is crashing with Error : SerdeEncodeMspack(Syntax("path contains invalid UTF-8 characters")).

Is there any way to encode a struct with invalid utf-8 charcters without skipping it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `PathBuf`s are serialized as strings by serde. You could store an `OsString` in your struct instead, which gets serialized as raw bytes. Alternatively, you could use a newtype wrapper or a custom serialization function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use a [custom de/serialize function](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#with) to convert it to/from an OsString when serializing?

Something like this should work.

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::ffi::OsString;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Demo {
    #[serde(with = "path_handling")]
    path: PathBuf,
}

mod path_handling {
    use super::*;
    use serde::de::Deserializer;
    use serde::ser::Serializer;
    pub fn serialize<S>(p: &PathBuf, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        p.as_os_str().serialize(serializer)
    }
    pub fn deserialize<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<PathBuf, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        Ok(OsString::deserialize(deserializer)?.into())
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get what are you suggesting. Could you please help me an example?

Comment: @KeshavPrince Serde serializes paths as strings (so assumes they're well-formed strings), Holloway suggests implementing serialization by hand to allow for non-utf8 paths e.g. https://gist.github.com/ripx80/33f80618bf13e3f4964b0d75c62bfd28 this way you can return e.g. a plain `Vec<u8>` with no validation.

Comment: @KeshavPrince have added an example that should give you something to work from.

Comment: Note that this code will not compile on non-Unix platforms because it uses `std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt`.

Comment: @user4815162342 I did mention that: "You will have to adjust it to handle non-unix systems"

Comment: @Holloway Ah, didn't notice that. But you might want to at least hint how such an adjustment would be performed?

Comment: So, In case you windows what should I do? Because we build our library in both linux as well as windows.
Is there any way which is compatibile for both linux and windows?

Comment: You could use `#[cfg(...)]` to modify the module the serialization uses. Windows has an equivalent `std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt` trait but only offers conversion to u16 so the serialized form would not be portable from one system to the other. Is it required to work with both or just either?

Comment: Yeah, it is required to work on both linux and windows. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Also, for my use case serialization and deserialization are happening on same platform but that platform could be either linux or windows.

Comment: @KeshavPrince, I have replaced all of the OS specific code so it should work the same on either Windows or Linux. Not sure how OsString's de/serialialization handles writing and reading from different platforms but that *might* work as well.

Comment: Thanks @Holloway. I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: @Holloway I tried the code you shared. But I am getting error from server side : message="msgpack: invalid code=81 decoding string/bytes length". Is there anything wrong with this approach. Is there any other way to acheive platform independence?

Comment: For valid utf-8 with default encoder for struct {path: "/root/bkpset/男人.txt"}, I am getting this buf = [112, 97, 116, 104, 183, 47, 114, 111, 111, 116, 47, 98, 107, 112, 115, 101, 116, 47, 231, 148, 183, 228, 186, 186, 46, 116, 120, 116], But when I tried doing it with the code above I got [112, 97, 116, 104, 196, 23, 47, 114, 111, 111, 116, 47, 98, 107, 112, 115, 101, 116, 47, 231, 148, 183, 228, 186, 186, 46, 116, 120, 116,]
There is only difference in 5th and 6th element. all others are same, can anybody tell me what those element signify?

Answer (score 1):

For most projects, it is worth asking whether it is worth the pain to try and support non-UTF-8 paths, or if you can just reject them at the boundaries of your application.

I maintain a project called [camino](https://crates.io/crates/camino/). This library provides `Utf8Path` and `Utf8PathBuf`, which are similar to `Path` and `PathBuf` but with a type-level assertion that they contain valid UTF-8. This greatly simplifies path handling at the cost of some flexibility (but that flexibility is often a mirage anyway, as the "makefile problem" listed in the README explains).